# Getting specific functions that need to be tested with code coverage

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, code-coverage, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm working on some new node.js modules / apps and I'm writing tests for the functions.

I'm looking into the code coverage for the first time. I just got `istanbul` & `mocha` up and running.

```
$ istanbul cover _mocha -- -R dot
```

And it prints out this nice report.

```
․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․

  225 passing (931ms)

=============================================================================
Writing coverage object [/endeavor/coverage/coverage.json]
Writing coverage reports at [/endeavor/coverage]
=============================================================================

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 87.59% ( 120/137 )
Branches     : 87.5% ( 14/16 )
Functions    : 74% ( 37/50 )
Lines        : 87.5% ( 119/136 )
================================================================================
```

However I'm looking for specifics, like what functions aren't being tested or "aren't covered". Istanbul also creates some files within a `coverage` directory, one of which is a `html` file, with no more info then what I get in the terminal.

How do I get a report of functions that aren't being tested? Is there a way to get this information from Istanbul, or another module?

Comment: When I viewed the HTML report in a web browser it nicely colour coded (orange) functions that were never called. It also shows you branches that aren't reached. It might be in the CSS - are you sure it's finding the stylesheet?

Comment: @eddiewould Ah! I have all my modules in a `lib` folder, I clicked it and found each individual file with diffs! Thanks.

Comment: @eddiewould What is a branch?

Comment: Code branch as in if (x) do y else do z - y and z are the branches.

Comment: @eddiewould thanks a bunch!